# Login from React Native mobile App into my Laravel Web App

Tags: laravel, react-native, laravel-passport, secret-key

I have a Laravel web application (both frontend and backend) that uses the integrated auth scaffolding.

Now I want to create a React Native app where users will be able to login into my Laravel app (entering their email and password).

I installed Laravel Passport on my backend and I want to use the Password Grant Tokens. So, in order to get an access token, my mobile app would need to send a POST request to my backend including the client id, client secret, email, password. However, this means the client id and secret are hardcoded in the mobile app code.

Is this the correct approach to do it? I have read that hardcoding secrets in mobile code is not secure, but in this case there's no risk of 'impersonation' since it's my own unique app anyway, right? I'm new to this and a bit confused.

Comment: Can't the client secret be part of the API itself?

Answer (score 1):

Don't hard code secrets, it is readable as plain text - https://react-native.canny.io/feature-requests/p/obfuscation-or-encryption-the-android-bundlejs-file